# Single object deleting multiple instances in database

Tags: class, oop

I have a class of Job which has a create method and update method, which in turn updates and creates single jobs in the database.

I now want to delete all jobs from the database where the date is not today's date. I also want to get all the jobs in the database.

In object-orientated programming is there a standard way of performing this? Or is there a design pattern suitable for this?

I was thinking of creating a JobHelper class to deal with getting all the jobs back out the database and deleting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as option: you need a collection, it is unspecified container for an set of objects. A common use of it is for groups of domain objects, which belong to separate layer, that handles the business domain logic.

So create new type "collection" which contain a list of objects, and manipulate  methods ( declare the main methods for work with collections such as delete all / get all).

You can use lazy load pattern and you can use domain model pattern to encapsulate your business logic such as "delete all jobs from the database where the date is not today's date. etc"